Leaky Overflow Gasket on a cast iron bathtub
I have a leaky overflow gasket on an old cast iron baththb.
I haven't succeeded to unscrew the overflow using my fingers, I suppose a special kind of wrench is needed.
I have seen gasket kits that seal from behind, and I suspect that this is not good for a cast iron tub that can rust.
I suspect that if/when I manage to unscrew the overflow ring, I will find more rust around the hole.
I'm wondering if silicon caulking would not be a better solution, since I can ensure that the seal goes around the enamel, and can never get to the rust.


The reason for not using silicone is that it makes it very difficult to take apart in the future. If you think you are having a hard time disassembling it now, think how hard it would be if it were glued in place with silicone.
All that is typically used is a tapered rubber (or foam-rubber) overflow gasket, which is placed on the back side of the tub, between the overflow horn and the back of the tub wall. A positive seal is not really needed because the area is never submerged (only seeing splashed water, really).
If your concern is existing and/or future corrosion, then properly repair it (e.g., remove the rust and coat the area with 2-part epoxy porcelain repair paint) prior to reassembling.

The problem I see with a "back side" gasket, is that I need to make the hole perfectly rust proof. Since there is already some rust, it has to be perfectly executed. The silicon solution seems to be more forgiving, as it would block water from coming in contact with the metal that has lost enamel. What I'm unsure about silicon is the durability.
